# Valet is not working with php.8 Nginx return Bad Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, macos, nginx, laravel-valet

Hi I have try to update php to 8.0 but always there a problem with valet to read the new version
and I try to solve it without specific instructions but this time is stucked
I will abbreviated my question and print `valet diagnose`

`valet --version`

> Laravel Valet 2.14.1

`brew services list`

```
dnsmasq    error   root          /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
httpd      stopped
mysql      started mohammedalama /usr/local/opt/mysql/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx      error   root          /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
php        error   root          /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.php.plist
redis      started mohammedalama /usr/local/opt/redis/homebrew.mxcl.redis.plist
supervisor started mohammedalama /usr/local/opt/supervisor/homebrew.mxcl.supervisor.plist
```

`brew list --formula --versions | grep -E "(php|nginx|dnsmasq|mariadb|mysql|mailhog|openssl)(@\d\..*)?\s"`

```
dnsmasq 2.84
mysql 8.0.19
nginx 1.19.8
openssl@1.1 1.1.1k
php 8.0.3
```

`php -v`

```
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2021 20:45:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

`php --ini`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/8.0
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/error_log.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini
```

`nginx -v`

> nginx version: nginx/1.19.8

`sudo nginx -t`

```
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

`sudo /usr/local/opt/php/sbin/php-fpm -y /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf --test`

```
[04-Apr-2021 11:20:10] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
[04-Apr-2021 11:20:10] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf'
[04-Apr-2021 11:20:10] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

`ls -al /Library/LaunchAgents | grep homebrew`

```
output is empty
```

`ls -al /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep homebrew`

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   657 Apr  4 11:03 homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   571 Apr  4 11:03 homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   628 Apr  4 11:03 homebrew.mxcl.php.plis
```

`ls -al /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep "com.laravel.valet."`

```
output is empty
```

Comment: NGINX returns Bad Gateway because the FPM is not running. Have you seen this error messages: `[04-Apr-2021 11:20:10] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
[04-Apr-2021 11:20:10] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf'
[04-Apr-2021 11:20:10] ERROR: FPM initialization failed`. Check your FPM setup first.

Comment: I figured out missing files but I can't create it like php-fpm.log and so on can you help with link to setup it at Big Sur or uninstall it and install fresh setup

Answer (score 4):

You are using Mac OS right? `sudo brew services list` shows `php error root`, so it seems like php-fpm is failing to start.
I had a similar problem, but I found this github issue:
https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/269

At first, I changed php version of valet by:

```
$ valet use php@8.0
$ sudo brew services stop php
$ brew services stop php
$ valet install
```

Then, following the comment of yratof of the github issue, I copied
`/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf`
to
`/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.conf`. Then run:

```
$ valet install
$ valet restart
```

Then check the php's status again by

```
$ sudo brew services list
```

If php's error is removed, I think valet will work properly.